# Perl Regex not matching

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to match lines from a file and extract a certain part.
My Regex works with all online testers I could find but not with my perl.
I'm on version v5.10.0 and cannot update.

The regex looks like this:

```
sub parse_bl_line {
    if ($_[0] =~ m/^copy\s+.*?\s+(.*?\_.*)/) {
             return $1;
    } else {
             log_msg("Line discarded: $_[0]", 4);
     return "0";
    }
```

}

A couple lines of test data which should match (only the last matches):

```
@bl_lines = (
"copy xxxxxx_/cpu     b_relCAP_R3.0-1_INT5_xxxxx_cpu_p1",
"copy xxxxxxxx_/va_xxx_parameters    b_relCAP_R3.0-1_INT5_xxxxx_va_xxx_parameters_p1",
"copy xxxxxxxx_/xxxxxxx_view.tcl      b_relCAP_R3.0-1_INT5_xxxxxx_view.tcl_p0",
"copy xxxxx_/xxxxxarchivetool.jar   b_relEARLY_DROP1_xxxxxarchivetool.jar_xx");
```

And calling the function:

```
foreach(@bl_lines) {
    $file=parse_bl_line($_);
    if ($file !~ "0") {
            log_msg("Line accepted: $_", 4);
            log_msg("File extracted: $file", 4);
    }else { 
            log_msg("Line rejected: $_", 2);
    }
```

}

I'm trying to match the last part e.g.

```
b_relEARLY_DROP1_xxxxxarchivetool.jar_xx
```

Output looks the following:

```
20120726 13:15:34 - [XXX] ERROR: Line rejected: copy xxxxxx_/cpu     b_relCAP_R3.0-1_INT5_xxxxx_cpu_p1
20120726 13:15:34 - [XXX] ERROR: Line rejected: copy xxxxxxxx_/va_xxx_parameters    b_relCAP_R3.0-1_INT5_xxxxx_va_xxx_parameters_p1
20120726 13:15:34 - [XXX] ERROR: Line rejected: copy xxxxxxxx_/xxxxxxx_view.tcl      b_relCAP_R3.0-1_INT5_xxxxxx_view.tcl_p0
20120726 13:15:35 - [XXX] INFO: Line accepted: copy xxxxx_/xxxxxarchivetool.jar   b_relEARLY_DROP1_xxxxxarchivetool.jar_xx 
20120726 13:15:35 - [XXX] INFO: File extracted: b_relEARLY_DROP1_xxxxxarchivetool.jar_xx
```

**Hint**
I did some of the testing that @BaL proposed and found out that the pattern matching works without the selection parenthesis.

```
if ($_[0] =~ m/^copy\s+.+?\s+.+?\_.+$/) {
```

Comment: What *does* your Regex match? Can you exchange `return $1` for `say $1` and show us the output from your test input? See @Bal's comment below.

Comment: [Works for me!](http://codepad.org/o2nD2xJu) The mistake isn't here. Show your **whole code**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The test :  `if ($file !~ "0") {` is true when `$file` doesn't contain a `0` at any position which is the case of the last string only.

I guess you want to use : `if ($file ne '0') {` or even shorter : `if ($file) {`

Apart of this you should really `use strict;` and  `use warnings` always.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to match ? The last part ?
Don't use * if you know that you have something to match, use + instead :

```
if ($_[0] =~ m/^copy\s+.+?\s+(.\+?)$/) {
    return $1;
}
```

Comment: That didn't help unfortunately, same result

Comment: What happens if you print out `$1` after matching the followings:`$_[0] =~ m/^copy(.+)$/`, then
`$_[0] =~ m/^copy\s+(.+)$/`, then
`$_[0] =~ m/^copy\s+.+(.+)$/`, etc. until you find where your pattern goes wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that the last line of your test file is the only one that doesn't end with a "\n".  Funny little buggers are always getting in the way.....

Comment: That is not the problem, I'm using a test which matches every line on it's own.

Answer (score 0):

Change the comparison operator in your if statement from !~ to ne as you are making a string comparison. When I make this change, all log lines were accepted.

I tested this on perl 5.14.2, not 5.10, but I didn't use any special features. Give it a go! code is below:

```
use 5.14.2;

sub log_msg{
    say shift;  
}

sub parse_bl_line {
    if ($_[0] =~ m/^copy\s+.*?\s+(.*?\_.*)/) {             
        return $1;     
    }
    else {              
        log_msg("Line discarded: $_[0]", 4);      
        return "0";     
    }
}

my @bl_lines = ( 
    "copy xxxxxx_/cpu                    b_relCAP_R3.0-1_INT5_xxxxx_cpu_p1",
    "copy xxxxxxxx_/va_xxx_parameters    b_relCAP_R3.0-1_INT5_xxxxx_va_xxx_parameters_p1", 
    "copy xxxxxxxx_/xxxxxxx_view.tcl     b_relCAP_R3.0-1_INT5_xxxxxx_view.tcl_p0", 
    "copy xxxxx_/xxxxxarchivetool.jar    b_relEARLY_DROP1_xxxxxarchivetool.jar_xx"
);  

foreach(@bl_lines) {     
    my $file = parse_bl_line($_);     
    if ($file ne "0") {    # Changed the comparison operator here         
        log_msg("Line accepted: $_", 4);             
        log_msg("File extracted: $file", 4);
    }
    else {              
        log_msg("Line rejected: $_", 2);     
    } 
}
```